# How to split a String result from a JSON URL to individual java objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have wrote code that returns data of a JSON url.
The data is stored as a String and here is an example of the output;

```
{

"status": "success",

"records": [

    {
        "timestamp": 1381312251599,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 17
    },

    {
        "timestamp": 1381312281599,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 17
    },

    {
        "timestamp": 1381312311599,
        "deviceId": "288",
        "temperature": 17
    }
]
}
```

here is a sample of the code used to get this information;

```
String jsonString = callURL("http://localhost:8000/eem/api/v1/metrics/temperature/288");
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

What I need help for is creating a Status field and then a records array which will hold the Timestamp, DeviceId, Temperature and there values.

I have tried looking at GSON, but I can't understand it

If anyone had any help, it would be great, thanks

Comment: What did you not understand? Did you give it try? Where is the code you tried, and what's the error you're getting in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy, paste and run this:

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Question {

    class Record {
        Long timestamp;
        String deviceId;
        Long temperature;
    }

    class Container {
        List<Record> records;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"status\": \"success\", \"records\": [{\"timestamp\": 1381222871868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 },{\"timestamp\": 1381222901868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 },{\"timestamp\": 1381222931868,\"deviceId\": \"288\",\"temperature\": 17 } ]} ";

        Gson g = new Gson();
        Container c = g.fromJson(json, Container.class);
        for (Record r : c.records)
            System.out.println(r);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. you should create a java class matching your json structure.

e.g.

```
public class Response {
     String status;
     List<Record> records;
}

public class Record {
     long timestamp;
     int deviceId;
     int temperature;
}
```

And than provide your json and `Response.class` to gson.

Comment: Ok so I create the classes but how do I provide a json and Response.class to gson?
Sorry I am still trying to get my head around all of this

Comment: Here is an example https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Answer (score 0):

I use jackson and it's quite simple.

You need to create appropriate java classes which have same properties as your jsonString has.

You need to create something like this

```
class Record {
   private Long timestamp;
   private Integer deviceId;
   private Integer temperature;

   // getters and setters ...
}

class Response {

  private String status;
  private List<Record> records;

   // getters and setters ...

}
```

and then

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Comment: With the last two lines of code there, where do I put it? I tried my main method but I couldn't because of it being void